# Facebook place check in

Tags: facebook

I have a facebook page/place for my business. I want to display on my website in real time people that checked in. It is possible?

Comment: This is not a fully realized question and doesn't show enough individual effort. But there is a kernel of interesting here, if you could just flesh it out and do some of the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Can, All you need to do is setup a token with your facebook account that will allow you to access the information.
Token Info:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Checkins: https://graph.facebook.com/me/checkins?access_token=...
Then you hit that url with your token and it returns a list of people that have checked in.